# Change Shipping table rates based on custom option selection

Tags: magento-1.9

I have added  weight,qty and special price to custom option.its working fine .
but problem is that shipping rates which is applied by shipping_tablerates are not changing based 
on that custom weight option , it will change based on default weight of the product.
 I want to change shipping table rates based on custom option selection.
Thanks in advance.